# jQuery plugin for toggle show/hide sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I have here 3 different divs. How to change the animation of hide/show div from left to right? And automatically change the width of framecontentTop and maincontent when the #framecontentLeft show/hide?

See this link. That's the animation I want to do. http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1421/a-jQuery-plugin-for-toggle-showhide-sidebar

Any help please?

This is my codes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#framecontentLeft").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $("#framecontentLeft").slideToggle();
    });

});
</script>
<style>
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%; 
    }

    #framecontentLeft, #framecontentTop{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 150px; /*Width of left frame div*/
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
    background-color: silver;
    color: white;
    }

    #framecontentTop{ 
    left: 150px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 120px; /*Height of top frame div*/
    overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
    background: green;
    color: white;
    }

    #maincontent{
    position: fixed; 
    left: 150px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
    top: 120px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto; 
    }

    .innertube{
    margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each DIV (to provide padding)*/
    }

    * html body{ /*IE6 hack*/
    padding: 120px 0 0 200px; /*Set value to (HeightOfTopFrameDiv 0 0 WidthOfLeftFrameDiv)*/
    }

    * html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    }

    * html #framecontentTop{ /*IE6 hack*/
    width: 100%;
    }

.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
</style>


<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>


<div id="framecontentLeft">
    <div class="innertube">
 <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="framecontentTop">
    <div class="innertube">

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="maincontent">
    <div class="innertube">

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just created this jsfiddle for you. I tried to include as much of your code as I could but I think it will be of help to you if you have a version for trying things out.

As you can see, you have to use jQuerys animate function to really animate the div sliding in. Referencing your example, there is also a github source given, so do have a look there and see how he did the animation.

```
$('.sidebar').animate({
    marginLeft: "0px",
    opacity: "1"
  }, 1000);
```

Here is the complete fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/n9MLk/

I also included kind of a list view for you to display content of the slider. I hope this helps you.

Comment: wow nice work. But I have 1 concern, about in page content. Because when sidebar shows the output in page affecting by width.

Comment: Just last one concern.

Comment: Umm what do you mean exactly by affecting by width?